# Unable to extract JWT Token on request receive

Tags: node.js, jwt, http-headers, express-jwt

I have an architecture which involves two NodeJS microservices. The workflow is as follows:

- User accesses a URL (localhost:8090) and gets registerd in the database through microservice 1
- After registration the user is redirected to service 2 which runs on localhost:3000

I'm trying to pass the JWT token from service 1 to service 2 through headers but I'm unable to receive it in service 2 as part of the headers.

Request from service 1 (localhost:8090):

```
    res.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ token); 
    res.redirect(302, `http://localhost:3000`)
```

Receive at service 2 (localhost:3000):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
});
```

The output of console.log is

```
{ host: 'localhost:3000',
  accept:
   'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  cookie:
   'connect.sid=....; csrftoken=...',
  'user-agent':
   '...',
  'accept-language': 'en-us',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

Comment: the client sets the request headers not the server

Comment: Oh wow. I was completely wrong then. In that case, what would be the best way to sign a  new JWT token and send it along with the redirect?

Comment: I thought about this for a sec and moved on ;p, I don't think its possible as it would be a security issue, imagine a XSS which just send the user to an endpoint and its sets something then redirects elsewhere.. I think the only solution to your issue as they are essentially 2 different sites is to get the token from service 1 in a header, then save that header in memory, then do an ajax call to service 2 with the header, then issue a new token based from that, if your using jwt both token privates will need to be the same anyway to validate on server 2, so why not just do all on server 2?